# What is Laplace operator of Schwarzschild-Spherical coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

This is the Laplace operator of Spherical coordinates:

[image: Laplace operator of Spherical coordinates]

What is the [Laplace operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) of Schwarzschild-Spherical coordinates?

where the [Differential displacement of Schwarzschild-Spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) is:

$$d{\bf{l}}=(1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1/2}dr\hat{\bf{r}}+rd\theta{\bf\hat{\theta}}+\sin{\theta}rd\phi{\bf\hat{\phi}}$$

Comment: I've linked the appropriate Wiki article under "Laplace operator". There's even an explicit formula to calculate it from the metric there - what is your question?

Comment: Hi Achmed. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry

Comment: for the generalisation of the laplacian operator in riemannian manifolds and derivation of its form in local coordinates you can also check http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hg94/pdst11/pdst11_sphere.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to calculate the laplacian in the spacial surface of $t$ constant. If the global metric is defined as:

$$
ds^2 = (1-\frac{r_s}{r}) \, dt^2 + (1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1} \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\theta^2 + r^2 \, \sin^2(\theta) \, d\phi^2
$$

The metric on the surface $t$ constant is
$$
ds^2 =  (1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1} \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\theta^2 + r^2 \, \sin^2(\theta) \, d\phi^2
$$

So your metric written in matrix form is:
$$
[g_{ij}]=\begin{pmatrix}
(1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1} && 0 && 0 \\
0 &&  r^2 && 0  \\
0 && 0 &&  r^2 \, \sin^2(\theta)
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The laplacian operator can be written in terms of this matrix elements as other people pointed in the comments. The general formula can be found in wikipedia as
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = \sum_{ij} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det(g)|}} \partial_i \left(g^{ij} \sqrt{|\det(g)|} \partial_j \phi \right)
$$
Where $g^{ij}$ is the inverse of the matrix of the metric $g_{ij}$. So
$$
[g^{ij}]=\begin{pmatrix}
(1-\frac{r_s}{r}) && 0 && 0 \\
0 &&  \frac{1}{r^2} && 0  \\
0 && 0 && \frac{1}{ r^2 \, \sin^2(\theta)}
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you can use the formula above for get the laplacian you want.